# How to configure Swagger APIKey using request header?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, api-key, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

my Swagger APIKey configuration doesn't work.
The header is not sent with the request.
Please help. What am I doing wrong?

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKeyAuth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Scheme = "ApiKeyAuth",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Name = "X-API-Key",
                Description = "APIKey security scheme"
            });
        }
```

[My Swagger request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM2Fa.jpg)

Comment: You also need `c.AddSecurityRequirement(...)` - see the 2nd example in https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-security-definitions-and-requirements

Comment: @Helen Thank you very much! Your proposal solves my problem.

Comment: Can you post your solution here please?

Comment: @Pawel
`c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "ApiKey" }
                        },
                        new[] { "readAccess", "writeAccess" }
                    }
                });`